# Scala collection sum to work with overloaded addition

Tags: scala, collections, sum, operator-overloading, implicit

I am trying to make an overloaded addition operator work with collections' `sum` method. For example, for

```
final case class Probability(val value: Double) {
  def +(that: Probability): Probability =
    Probability(this.value + that.value)
}

List(Probability(0.4), Probability(0.3)).sum
```

I get the below error messages:

```
Error:(6, 109) could not find implicit value for parameter num:
  Numeric[A$A42.this.Probability]
def get$$instance$$res0 = /* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */
  List(Probability(0.4), Probability(0.3)).sum;}

Error:(6, 109) not enough arguments for method sum: 
  (implicit num: Numeric[A$A42.this.Probability])A$A42.this.Probability.
Unspecified value parameter num.
def get$$instance$$res0 = /* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */
   List(Probability(0.4), Probability(0.3)).sum;}
```

I reckon this has to do something with `implicit`s (as the error message clearly states), but I don't know where it should be defined or added (in the case class `Probability`, its companion object, or after `sum`?), or how it should look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum method works with the type class Numeric[T], so if you want to call sum over your own "number type", you need to define an instance of Numeric[Probability].

The best place to put a custom type class definition is the object companion.

```
object Probability {

  implicit val probabilityNumberic = new Numeric[Probability] {
    def plus(x: Probability, y: Probability): Probability = ???
    def minus(x: Probability, y: Probability): Probability = ???
    def times(x: Probability, y: Probability): Probability = ???
    def negate(x: Probability): Probability = ???
    def fromInt(x: Int): Probability = ???
    def toInt(x: Probability): Int = ???
    def toLong(x: Probability): Long = ???
    def toFloat(x: Probability): Float = ???
    def toDouble(x: Probability): Double = ???
    def compare(x: Probability, y: Probability): Int = ???
  }

}
```

Alternatively if you dont want to define the Numeric[T] instance or if you want a Probability as result, you can use reduce instead of sum.

```
List(Probability(0.4), Probability(0.3)).reduce(_ + _)
```

or reduceOption if the list could be empty.

About where you can define your `Numeric[Probability]`,you must take into account implicits's scope.It is common to define a default implementation on the object companion, but you can create it before sum call, through an import, or you can use it explicitly. It depends on what you need.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianCelestino for the answer and for emphasising the importance of scope. My only comment is that you misspelled Numeric as Numberic in your text and code once, other than that it's very informative.